# excel ttest array with condition

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

i don't want vb code answer for this one. I was just wondering how to do this, for example in MS Excel there is a TTEST function which takes in array1, array2, tails, and type.

My question is for array1 for example I want to put A1:A3, but I don't want some of the values and do not want them counted as a total number of available values either.

For example, A1=0, A2=-3, A3=2... How is it possible to say

```
   array1={A1:A3 where value >=0}
```

So array1 will be: 0 and 2, and total number of elements in array1 is 2.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like The TTEST formula ignores any "FALSE" value in its array so the following might help you (Remember pressing Ctrl+Shift+ENTER):

```
{=TTEST(IF(A2:A3>=0;A2:A3);If(B2:B3>0;B2:B3);2;1)}
```

Important, no cell in the array can be empty.

Hope it Helps.